# How do I print a python code on paper

Tags: python

I need to print a python source code on a paper. What is the easiest way to do that from the shell.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ cat yourFileName.py | lpr
```

in UNIX, if you have a printer configured.

Comment: Why `cat blah | lpr`? Why not just `lpr filename.py`? Seems like useless abuse of a `cat`.

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: @yoda Shouldn't that be `cat, useless uses, hm?` :)

Comment: Acutally, here is what the man page says,   "lpr  submits  files  for  printing. Files named on the command line are
sent to the named printer (or the default destination if no destination is  specified).  If  no files are listed on the command-line, lpr reads the print file from the standard input."
The piping is just doing what happens anyway; the contents of the file are directed to lpr's standard input. Whist a bit verbose, it is functionally equivalent to lpr yourFileName.py

Answer (score 4):

[`a2ps`](http://www.gnu.org/s/a2ps/) has a nice syntax highlighting (for Python and many other languages), configuration of headers+footers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `lgrind` in the past for pretty-printed source output; I was pleased with it, but the Ubuntu `Description` field for `lgrind` suggests using the `listings` tool from `texlive-latex-recommended` package instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want prettyprinting, [enscript](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/) -E can do that.